# Vector replacing value inside itself without accessing it

Tags: java, arrays, vector, overwrite

I ran into a problem lately which involves using a Vector of arrays (or arrayList<>)
Basically, i put my elements into a small array that I then put into my Vector, but when all the small array has been loaded into the big one, and the small one overwrites the new data (which is what I want), the Vector overwrites too
This is not what I want, because I end up haveing 280 equals element, like the Vector has a linked relation I don't understand

I have searched also in old posts related to my problem, but the solution they have dont suit my problem, because I dont encounter the ones that are answered

Follows my code

```java
package DataManager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

public class LeggiJsonNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String urlString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.json";
        Vector<String[]> bigArray = new Vector<String[]>(); 

        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        
        String line;    

        String[] smallArray = new String[19];
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if(line.equals("[")) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                smallArray[j]=line;
                j++;
                
                if(line.equals("    },") || line.equals("    }")) {
                    bigArray.add(i,smallArray);
                    i++;
                    j=0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding the same array.

If you want to add a different array each time, create a new array, e.g.:

```
bigArray.add(i,smallArray);
smallArray = new String[10];
```

or add a copy of the array:

```
bigArray.add(i, Arrays.copyOf(smallArray, smallArray.length));
```

---

Note that `Vector` is essentially deprecated; use `ArrayList` instead.

Also note that you don't need to keep track of where you're adding to `bigArray`: `bigArray.add(smallArray)` will do the same, just without the housekeeping of `i`.

Also also note that it doesn't look like you are taking any steps to ensure that you only assign elements to valid indexes, for example you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `j` reaches 10; conversely, you're not actually checking that you are using all 10 elements of the array when you add it to `bigArray`.

You might find it more straightforward to use `List` (specifically, an `ArrayList`) instead of arrays, which will resize as required.

Also also also: it looks like you're parsing JSON: use a JSON library.

Comment: The array thing you said helped me out and it is what I needed
Also, i need to read with some kind of reader the JSON file, and then i will use the library
This is why I wanted to do what I did
Thanks for the help, I really needed it